# Using PhantomJS and IntelliSense in VS2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, autocomplete, phantomjs, intellisense

I want to use autocompletion for **PhantomJS** with **IntelliSense** in **Visual Studio 2015**.
Is there any way to set it up?

Whast do I have to do that IntelliSense recognizes the content of the `page.evaluate()` as **JavaScript** code?
I want autocompletion for things like `document.getElementById()`

Means no answer that this is impossible?